# Arduino IC22 Display Countdown timer not transforming from double digit to one digit

Tags: c++, arduino

So recently i started to learn C++ and Arduino. For my training i use an IC22 Display which I connected to my breadboard. I tried creating a simple countdown timer from 20 seconds all the way to 0. However I ran into a problem where the IC 22 Display would still display the number 0 everytime it the countdown goes below 10. So 9 would be 90 and 8 would 80.How do i remove the 0 from my display? Could someone check what is wrong with my code?

```
lcd.begin(20,4);
lcd.clear();
lcd.print("Timer:");
lcd.setCursor(0,1);
lcd.print("Seconds:");

}


void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
 for (int i=20;i<=20;--i){
    lcd.setCursor(8,1);
    lcd.print(i);
    delay(1000);
    if (i <=0){
    break;
  }
}
}
```

1

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code, but it just does not know that you expect it to pad numbers right-aligned to 2 digits with spaces... because you didn't tell it so. You have various options: you can clear first, you can cursor one further to the right if you only have 1 digit, you can print a leading space if you only have 1 digit, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try use

```
lcd.clear()
```

just before cursor setting inside your loop.